# Drop columns if number of NaNs equals the threshold parameter

Tags: python, pandas

```
def drop_cols_na(df, threshold):

  df.drop(df.isna[col for col in df if ....]) 
  return df
```

Hard coding is relatively simple but I want to create a quick program that changes the threshold of when to drop a column depending on the input parameter I choose. For example: drop columns if number of nan's equate to 50%, 60% and so on.

I have found a few examples to follow. But I am struggling to implement it into a  `def` function

the following line that must run without my changing is
`df=drop_cols_na(df)` which naturally returns an error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'threshold'"

Comment: There is a [`thresh`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna) parameter in pd.DataFrame.dropna.

Comment: @ScottBoston. This is the best answer! :-)

Comment: @ScottBoston appreciate the help. The current issue i have is that: despite whatever code i run for the function: the following code that I MUST use is missing one input argument.  
```df = drop_cols_na(df)```

Comment: I am bit confused, but you could set a default  something like `def drop_cols_na(df, threshold=10): ` then 'df = drop_cols_na(df)` will still work.

Comment: @ScottBoston  absolutely, managed to use some brain waves in the end. Appreciate the support !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test case:

```
>>> df
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0   1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
1   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
2   1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3   1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4   1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
5   NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
6   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
7   1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
8   1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
9   NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
10  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
11  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
12  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
13  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
14  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
15  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
16  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
17  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
18  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
19  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN

#   20%  15%  35%  30%  15%  15%  30%  15%  25%  20%   % of NaN
```

```
def drop_cols_na(df, threshold):
    return df[df.columns[df.isna().sum() / len(df) < threshold]]
```

Drop all cols where `NaN >= 0.25`:

```
>>> drop_cols_na(df, 0.3)
      0    1    4    5    7    9
0   1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2   1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
3   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
5   NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
6   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
7   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
8   1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
9   NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
10  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
11  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
12  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
13  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
14  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
15  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
16  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
17  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
18  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
19  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the columns where the condition is met. Then, drop them.

```
def drop_cols_na(df, threshold):
    cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].isna().sum()/df[col].shape[0]>threshold]
    df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
    return df
```